# Can't Right-Click Top Menu Bar

Tags: 11.04, unity, panel

I wanted to move the top menu bar to the bottom of my desktop, rather than the top.  Every tutorial I saw told me to right-click it and select "Properties," but I simply cannot right-click the menu bar.  No matter where the cursor is, there is no response.  No menu or anything.

Right-clicking works fine everywhere else.  Is there some hidden setting that's preventing me from messing with it?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @binarylife 11.04.  I'm booting from a CD for now, but I had it "properly" installed before with the same problem.

Comment: this is not a problem.This is the new interface for Ubuntu. If you don't like Unity you can switch back to Ubuntu Classic Desktop session which has the `gnome-panel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using Ubuntu 11.04 with Unity.
If you want to configure your Desktop in that way, you need to switch to Ubuntu Classic at the bottom of the login-screen.

There you can use the configurable Gnome-Panel the classic way.
If you don't want to miss the Unity Launcher Bar on the left, you could try to install docky and put it on the left of the Desktop. But it's not all the same like the Unity Launcher.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you are using the new Unity user interface.  The panel at the top is not provided by `gnome-panel`, so tutorials about `gnome-panel` won't necessarily be correct.

There is no way to move Unity's panel to another edge of the screen.

Comment: Well, that's rather inconvenient.